# Return results matching all of the requested items

Tags: mysql

I have a table with data like this:

```
+---------+---------+
| user_id | item_id |
+---------+---------+
|     125 |     375 |
|     125 |       2 |
|     125 |      12 |
|     125 |     375 |
|     283 |       2 |
|     283 |      11 |
|     118 |     375 |
|     118 |      12 |
+---------+---------+
```

And I'm trying to create a query that will return all users that have ALL of the requested items, which in this case the requested items are:

```
item_id IN (375, 12)
```

So this should be the result:

```
+---------+
| user_id |
+---------+
|     125 |
|     118 |
+---------+
```

Short of joining the table to itself, I'm not really sure how I would accomplish this.
One idea I thought of was to group it by: `user_id, item_id` then maybe put a count on it, but that will count the double record of `user_id: 125, item_id: 375` as 2, putting the total count for user_id 125 at 3, which has it's own set of problems such as returning users that have the same item twice vs. what I really need, which is a user that has both of the requested items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT item_id) = 2`, but I like to be more explicit—the following approach allows for arbitrary boolean logic:

```
SELECT   user_id
FROM     my_table
WHERE    item_id IN (375, 12)
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING   SUM(item_id = 375) AND SUM(item_id = 12)
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55a71/1/0).

This works in MySQL because it does not have true boolean types; instead, the "boolean" result of the comparisons is in fact an integer—`1` if true and `0` if false—therefore the summation over the group is zero if no match found and non-zero otherwise: such terms can be combined with logical operators due to MySQL's implicit type conversion back to "boolean" types.  In other RDBMS, one might have to use `CASE`:

```
HAVING   SUM(CASE WHEN item_id = 375 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
     AND SUM(CASE WHEN item_id =  12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```